# the joke about marie antoinette

Tags: meaning

*Robespierre walks into his new office, once the Queen's parlour: "So this is where she powdered her cheeks?" he remarks. A fellow revolutionary replies: "All four of them!" and they all collapse in raucous laughter. Kenneth Williams would have been proud.*

Can you please explain to me the point of this joke. What is it meant by the reply "All four of them"? Is there some sexual connotation contained? I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: How many cheeks do you have? 2 on your face and 2 around waist height...

Comment: (I will happily explain further if you don't understand my comment.)

Comment: So the revolutionary alludes to Antoinette's corpulent figure? I thought that boys from the Committee of Public Safety had a better sense of humor.

Comment: Such base humour is commonplace in the Kenneth Williams brand of comedy.

Comment: The *gluteus maximus* is a "butt cheek".  Even on a skinny person.

Comment: Did you check the definition of [**cheek**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/cheek)? *3. either of the buttocks.*

Comment: I don't agree with the close reason. Sure, you can find many obscure meanings by looking 'em up in a dictionary. How is a learner supposed to find the hidden meaning intended in a joke in the sea of different meanings for *cheek* in the dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two meanings here, a higher brow and a lower brow variant on the joke. The first is the sexual connotations discussed in the comments to your post: of two extra cheeks and showing her self off. At first I thought this was the only meaning, until I though of the phrase "two faced"<sup>1</sup>.

Twice as many faces, twice as many cheeks (you do the math!) I feel as though the higher brow one like this is much more likely to be the true meaning, judging from the (apparently) sophisticated context. I did google this to find some kind of evidence to back up my thoughts, but only came across a TV program [review](http://www.leicestermercury.co.uk/TV-Review-Terror-Robespierre-French-Revolution/story-12054883-detail/story.html) and this question again.

To surmise, I think that the joke means that she's two faced, but it's ambiguous.

---

<sup>1</sup>Two faced is defined as a person being deceptive or sly, quite possibly ready to betray people. From Google:

> "insincere and deceitful."

Some synonyms, too:

> deceitful, insincere, double-dealing, hypocritical, back-stabbing, false, untrustworthy, duplicitous, Janus-faced, deceiving, dissembling, dishonest; [More](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=two-faced%20meaning%20dictionary)

Comment: I think this is an interesting interpretation, although you might explain what "two-faced" means to save learners a dictionary look up.

Comment: @ColleenV Great idea! I hadn't even thought of that, so thanks! Edited now.